# Is O(cn) at least as fast as O(n) in a non asymptotically way?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

So first of all let me talk about the motivation for this question. Let's supose you have to find the minimum and the maximum values in an array. In this case, you wave two ways of doing so.

The first one consists in iterating over the array and finding the maximum value, then doing the same thing to find the minimum value. This solution is O(2n).

The second one consists in iterating over the array just one time and finding both the minimum and maximum value at the same time. This solution is O(n).

Even though the time complexity has been halved, for each iteration of the O(n) solution you now have twice as many instructions (ignoring how the compiler can possibly optmize these instructions) so I believe they should take the same amount of time to execute.

Let me give you a second example. Now you need to reverse an array. Again, you have two ways of doing so.

The first one is to create an empty array, iterate over the data array filling the empty array. This solution is O(n).

The second one is to iterate over the data array, swapping the 0th and n-1th elements, then the 1th and n-2th elements and so on ([using this strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm)) until you reach the middle of the array. This solution is O((1/2)n).

Again, even though the time complexity has been cutted in half, you have three times more instructions per iteration. You're iterating over (1/2)n elements, but for each iteration you have to perform three XOR instructions. If you were not to use XOR, but an auxiliary variable you would still need 2 more instructions to perform the variable swapping, so now I believe that o((1/2)n) should actually be worse than o(n).

Having said these things, my question is the following:

Ignoring space complexity, garbage collecting and the compiler possible optimizations, can I assume that having O(c1*n) and O(c2*n) algorithms so that c1 > c2, can I be sure that the algorithm that gives me O(c1*n) is as fast or faster than the one that gives me O(c2*n)?

This question is cool because it can make a difference on how I start writing code from here and on. If the "more complex" (c1) way is as fast as the "less complex" (c2) but more readable, i'm sticking with the "more complex" one.

Comment: You've mixed up the concepts of "time complexity" and "running time". The former is a purely academic concept. The latter is a practical engineering concept. If you're interested in what affects "running time", you need to remove the `time-complexity`, `big-o`, and `complexity-theory` tags. And you need to remove all mention of `O(...)` from the question. As is, all you're going to get is academic answers that say that constant factors don't matter.

Comment: You're asking a performance evaluation of your algorithms, you need to measure up your algos with real world data and use a profiler to gather those measurements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> c1 > c2, can I be sure that the algorithm that gives me O(c1*n) is as fast or faster than the one that gives me O(c2*n)?

The whole issue lies within the words "fast" or "faster". Computational complexity doesn't strictly measure what we intuitively understand as "fast". Without going into mathematical details (although it's a good idea: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), it answers the question "how fast it will go slower when my input grows". So if you have O(n^2) complexity you can roughly expect that doubling the size of the input will make your algorithm take 4 times more time. Whereas for linear complexity, 2 times bigger input gives only doubles the time. As you can see, it's relative, so any constants cancel out.

To sum up: from the way you ask your question, it doesn't seem the big-O notation is the correct tool here.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, if `c1` and `c2` are constants, `O(c1*n) === O(c2*c) === O(n)`. That is, the number of operations *per element* of your array of length `n` is completely irrelevant in this kind of complexity analysis.

All that it will tell you is that "it's linear". That is, if you have 1 bazillion operations for an array of length `n`, then you'll have 2 bazillion operations for an array of length `2*n` (plus or minus something that grows slower than linear).

> can I assume that having O(c1*n) and O(c2*n) algorithms so that c1 > c2, can I be sure that the algorithm that gives me O(c1*n) is as fast or faster than the one that gives me O(c2*n)?

Nope, not at all.

First, because the constants there are meaningless in that analysis. There's no way to put it: it is *absolutely irrelevant* whatever restrictions you put in `c1` and `c2` for big-O analysis. The whole idea is that it will *discard* those restrictions.

Second, because they don't tell you anything that would enable you to compare the two algorithms runtime for a ***specific* value of `n`**.

Such complexity analysis only enables you to compare the *asymptotic behavior* of algorithms. **Real-world problems in general don't care about where the asymptotes are**.

Assume that `A1(n)` is the number of operations Algorithm 1 needs for an input of length `n`, and `A2(n)` is the same for Algorithm 2. You could have:

- `A1(n) = 10n + 900`
- `A2(n) = 100n`

The complexity of both is `O(A1) = O(A2) = O(n)`. For small inputs, A2 is faster. For large inputs, A1 is faster. The point where they change is `n == 10`.

> This question is cool because it can make a difference on how I start writing code from here and on. If the "more complex" (c1) way is as fast as the "less complex" (c2) but more readable, i'm sticking with the "more complex" one.

Not only that, but also there's the fact that when you have 2 different algorithms that are *really* of different complexity classes (e.g., linear vs quadratic), it might still make sense to use the one of higher complexity as it may still be *faster*.

For example:

- `A3(n) = n^2`
- `A4(n) = n + 10^20`.

E.g., Algorithm 3 is quadratic, while Algorithm 4 is linear but it has a constant huge initialization time.

For inputs of size of up to around `n == 10^10`, *it will be faster to use the quadratic algorithm*.

It may very well be the case that *all* relevant inputs for your specific problem fall within that range, meaning that the quadratic algorithm would be the better, faster choice.

The bottom line is: for analyzing the *actual time* it will take to run an algorithm on a given input (or a given bounded range of inputs, as nearly all real-world problems are) and compare it with another algorithm, big-O analysis is meaningless.

Another way to put it: you're asking a practical "engineering" question (i.e., which option is better / faster) but trying to answer the question with a tool that's only useful for "theoretical" analysis. That tool is important, yes. But it has no chance of giving you the answer you're looking for, by design.

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't make myself clear, but my question is not if they have the same time complexity, but if I can assume that if c1 > c2 means that the algorithm that uses c1 is at least as fast as the one that uses c2.

Comment: @MiguelPinheiro - believe I addressed that very topic in the answer above, with examples.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, time complexity ignores constants. So `O((1/2)n) == O(n) == O(2n) == O(cn)`.

Your example of `O((1/2)n)` shows why this is the case, because the constants can measure units of anything, so comparing them is meaningless.

You can never tell which algorithm is faster based only on the time complexity. But, you can tell which one would be faster as n approaches infinity. Since constants are removed from the time complexity, they would be considered equal and therefore with `O(c1n)` and `O(c2n)` you still would not be able to tell which one is faster even as n approaches infinity.

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't make myself clear, but my question is not if they have the same time complexity, but if I can assume that if c1 > c2 means that the algorithm that uses c1 is at least as fast as the one that uses c2.

Comment: @MiguelPinheiro No, you can never tell which algorithm is faster based only on the time complexity. But, you can tell which one would be faster as n approaches infinity. Since constants are removed from the time complexity, they would be considered equal and therefore you still would not be able to tell which one is faster as n approaches infinity.

Answer (score 0):

(my theoretical computer science courses are a couple of decades ago)

O(cn) is O(n).

It's still a linear search over the array.

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't make myself clear, but my question is not if they have the same time complexity, but if I can assume that if c1 > c2 means that the algorithm that uses c1 is at least as fast as the one that uses c2.